# Better OOP Design?

Tags: c#

I have a class that needs access to global objects declared in another class. There is probably some keyword such as extern that will allow me to do this. Should I do it this way or would it be better if I make a static "GlobalObjects" class that I will allow all my classes to access and just access the objects as such: `GlobalObjects.Object1.foo();`?

Code snippet:

```
namespace Pong {
    public class Pong : Game {
            public Ball ball;
            public Paddle paddleOne;
            public Paddle paddleTwo;

            public Pong()
                : base() {
                graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
                Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            }
            // extra code
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `public`...?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: So just make all my classes public or have one public class that has access to everything?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: I've made the objects public and the main class public, but I still can't access the objects inside the main class because I don't have an instance of it. :|

Comment: If the objects aren't tied to an instance, make them static?

Comment: you are probably just going about it in the wrong way.  Can you show more of an example of what actual "globals" you need ?

Answer (score 1):

Global state is **in general** a bad practice. However, for applications where there are many, many objects that can interact with many, many other objects, it sometimes makes sense to have some sort of mechanism for those objects to easily find each other. Game design typically falls into this category, where objects in the game (player characters, NPCs, bad guys, items, etc) all need to be able to interact with each other frequently.

To solve this problem, there is a design pattern called "Registry", and it is very often used in [simple games](http://www.photonstorm.com/archives/1136/flash-game-dev-tip-1-creating-a-cross-game-communications-structure). The pattern is simple: you create a `Registry` class that is essentially a static list (or a bunch of static lists) of all the elements that need to interact with each other.

The registry pattern gains you ease of use and rapid development at the cost of maintainability and refactorability, so be careful that you use it appropriately. If you just start stuffing every possible object into it then you'll very quickly wind up with an unmanageable codebase. This pattern is tailored for simple games that are unlikely to be very complex, and Pong sounds like a good fit.

Comment: **Law of Demeter** can be violated a lot with an approach the OP is attempting to take.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes, the registry pattern intentionally violates the principle of least knowledge. As mentioned, it is a conscious tradeoff for cases where strictly following such a guideline would be unreasonable or otherwise too expensive given the size of the project. In the same way that a trivial to-do list application does not need a 3-tier design, a simple pong game does not always need to have perfect visibility scope and separation of concerns.

Comment: even with a registry, its much better not to do it with static members / lists etc

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on the previous comments / answers to this question.  I agree that global state generally indicates bad design.  State is generally kept in a data store, and therefore can be accessed as needed.  Oop design means that objects follow a set of principals such as the [Single Responsiblity Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Also that a behavior exists in one and only one class.

In your case, without knowing more about what you are trying to accomplish: when you say that you have global objects declared in another class what you could do is use the Gang of Four [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).  That is the global object is responsible for maintaining its instance and can pass this instance back to whoever needs to access it.  In this way you would not need another class (your 'global objects' class), which would be better as the fewer dependencies between classes the better.  Fewer dependencies between classes means the design is less brittle, which is to say that when you need to make changes it is less likely that bugs will be introduced by the change.